# How can I do in order to generate the makefile with ./configure?

Tags: c, makefile, configure, autoconf, automake

I am trying to install EZTrace which is a tool that aims at generating automatically execution trace from HPC. I downloaded the installation folder from here, https://eztrace.gitlab.io/eztrace/index.html. After extracting it, I found a README file:

```
Requirements
=============================================
In order to run EZTrace, you need the following software:

  * autoconf 2.63;

  * libelf or libbfd. Otherwise, only eztrace.old would be installed and the
    functionality would be limited, see the FAQ section.
    On Debian, libelf can be installed from command line by the following
    command: apt-get install libelf-dev

  * [Optional] Any MPI implementation.    

Building EZTrace
=============================================
At first, you need to configure EZTrace by invoking the configure script:

$ ./configure --prefix=<WHERE_YOU_INSTALL_EZTRACE>

Options to configure. You can pass several options to the configure script for
specifying where it should find the needed libraries:
--with-litl=$LITL_ROOT or ARG(=no): specify where LiTL is installed
--with-gtg=$GTG_ROOT: specify where GTG is installed.
--with-mpi=$MPI_ROOT: specify where MPI is installed. The mpi.h file must be
  located in the $MPI_ROOT/include/ directory.
--with-mpi-include=<PATH_TO_MPI.H>: specify the directory that contains the
  mpi.h file.
--with-papi=$PAPI_ROOT: specify where PAPI is installed. The papi.h file must be
  located in the $PAPI_ROOT/include directory and libpapi should be in 
  $PAPI_ROOT/lib

Once EZTrace is configured, just type:

$ make
$ make install
```

I checked if I have already installed the requirements (done). When reaching the `./configure` command, I faced a problem that I fixed by typing `autoreconf -i`.

The problem is that, after executing the `./configure` command and when executing the `make` command, I get this error:

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

(it is because the command ./configure doesn't generate a makefile as expected).
I only have `Makefile.am` & `Makefile.in`.

I try to check this block of commands:

```
aclocal
autoconf
autoheader
automake --add-missing
```

and I got:

```
autoheader: error: AC_CONFIG_HEADERS not found in configure.ac
automake: warning: LINK was already defined in condition USE_CUDA, which is included in condition TRUE ...
src/modules/cuda/Makefile.am:15: ... 'LINK' previously defined here
```

I want to mention that I'm located in a folder called

```
"/home/hakim/Téléchargements/eztrace-eztrace-1.1-9"
```

Any help to generate the makefile, please ?

Comment: The link you post contains a link to a tarball.  Why are you trying to bootstrp from the VCS rather than using the tarball?

Comment: <sigh>  I just downloaded the tarball and see that it is merely a snapshot of the VCS.  File a bug report; their tarball is ill formed.  They ought to be generating a tarball with `make dist` that would contain the Makefile.  They should not be asking the user to bootstrap the project.

Comment: The `configure` command is failing.  When it fails, it doesn't generate a makefile.  When it doesn't generate a makefile, you can't run `make`.  Implied by each step in the README file is, "if it fails stop and fix it so it works before continuing on to the next step".  Your question should be re-written to be, "why does configure fail with XYZ error and how can I make it work".  My suspicion is that the system was written to use some older (or newer) version of autoconf than the one you have.  It's too bad the author of the software didn't include the versions they tested with.

Comment: @MadScientist I installed autoconf 2.63 as written in the README. I still have the same problem.  `config.status: error: cannot find input file: Makefile.in`. Do you think my problem has no possible solution ?

Comment: There is a solution, but it will likely be a painful slog.  If Makefile.in doesn't exist (but where!?  There are 57 Makefile.am in this tarball!!), that indicates that automake (or autoreconf) is failing in one of components.  You'll need to examine the output of autoreconf in each subdirectory to figure out where it's failing.

Comment: This is one (of unfortunately many) example of a project that is trying to abuse the autotools and use them as a package management system.  Bundling dependencies like this is a disaster.  You should ask/plead/demand that the project maintainers provide a reasonable solution.  (eg, you should be able to get an rpm or a deb package so all the dependency tracking will be handled by a proper package management tool)

Comment: @WilliamPursell oww that's really a lot of work ! I will try to install  `hpctoolkit` in order to visualize what I need. It's a hard mission to try to trace and to visualize OpenMP program execution. Till now, I tried `eztrace` and `OMPTrace` but both don't work as I want. Thanks !

Comment: Asking for RPM or DEB files is a bridge too far.  That means that the developer has to worry about binary compatibility, different OS versions, etc. etc.  Part of the goal of FOSS is that we can have people who want to write software do that, and other people who want to build distributions do that.  They do not have to be and often are not the same people.  You can bug your distribution to provide these packages but asking the upstream developers to do so is too much.

Comment: in order to bootstrap the build-system run  `bootstrap`. in order to fix the bulid-system, send a bug-report.

Comment: _However_, it's true that autotools were not intended to be used with a bare repository distribution.  What's supposed to happen is that the developer uses autotools on their own system to generate a source distribution (usually as a tarball) and then users download that and compile it themselves, but without needing any autotools software: they just need a compiler and make.  That to me seems like a very reasonable request to make of the developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- don't run `autoheader` - the project is not setup to use it
- the `automake` warning is a *warning*, not an error.

usually, the simplest way to bootstrap an autotools-project is by running `autoreconf -fiv`.
that will create a `configure` script which you need to run in order to create the Makefile.

```sh
autoreconf -fiv
./configure
make
```

### EDIT: EZtraze

the original answer (above) was a generic answer to a generic question ("How can I generate the makefile with ./configure?").

With a specific project, like EZtrace, it usually helps to read the README.
You already quoted the README, but for whatever reasons, it seems that you left out the crucial bit:

```
Getting EZTrace
=============================================
* You can get the latest stable release on EZTrace website:
  http://eztrace.gforge.inria.fr/

* Current development version is available via GIT
  git clone git://scm.gforge.inria.fr/eztrace/eztrace.git

After getting the latest development version (from GIT), you need to run
'./bootstrap' and only then build the tool.
```

(both the git version **and** the release tarballs available on the page you have linked to contain this section).

It clearly tells you that you *must run `./bootstrap`* first.

So the answer to your question is: please read the documentation.

(also note that the build process for a specific software package is off-topic here in general; use the support forum for that software package)

Comment: I still have the same problem. the `./configure` command doesn't generate the makefile. I always get : `configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: error: cannot find input file: Makefile.in 
configure: error: ./configure failed for extlib/gtg`

Comment: Looks like `extlib/gtg/Makefile.in` does not exist. Is `eztrace` trying to deploy its dependencies in its VCS?  They ought not do that.

Comment: afaics, there are various problems with their VCS-setup (like checkedin [`autom4te.cache/` directories](https://gitlab.com/eztrace/eztrace/-/tree/master/extlib/gtg/autom4te.cache), checkedin [failed patch attempts](https://gitlab.com/eztrace/eztrace/-/blob/master/extlib/opari2/Makefile.in.rej) and generally outdaten and/or broken `m4`